# how to modify the scope of azure monitoring alert using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, alert, azure-monitoring

I have created a monitoring alert with scope as the entire subscription. I am getting an error while trying to modify the scope of an alert to a resource group within the subscription.

I tried using cli and is working but using terraform I am getting error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncrzh.png)

Comment: Please take a look here first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

The error image indicates that the log alert you are trying to create ***"already exists"*** in Azure with the same name. As far as I know, you simply changed the scope and trying the same deployment without making any other changes to the code. That is why it throws an error similar to one that already exists.

*There are two possibilities here:*

1. Rename the log alert and then deploy the template with the resource group as the scope.
2. Use `terraform import` to import an existing terraform resource into a terraform state file.

```bash
terraform import azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert.example /subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Insights/activityLogAlerts/<alertname>
```

It will be imported into terraform state file and now the error will disappear.

Refer to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75130449/19785512) worked by me for more information on `terraform import` functionality.

I created a monitoring log alert as given in [terraform registry template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_activity_log_alert) after making few changes, I was able to deploy it successfully with the alert trigger and an action group.

*Output in portal after deployment:*

[image]

[image]