# Azure "Diagnostic-Settings-Name" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have configured diagnostic settings for resources in my RG, every resource has unique name for the diagnostic settings when the same code is used to build a new env in other subscription, am reporting with the below error:

*Error:A resource with the ID "/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft./|" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" for more information.*

Find the code below:

```
resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "sb" {
 name                = "sb-test"
 location            = var.location
 resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
 sku                 = "Standard"
 tags = {
Environment = "${var.environment}"
Terraform   = "true"
}



resource "azurerm_servicebus_queue" "queue" {
name         = "queue-test"
namespace_id = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.counter.id
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "diagnostics" {
  name                       = "diagnostics-sb-${var.suffix}"
  target_resource_id         = 
  azurerm_servicebus_namespace.counter.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = var.log_analytics_workspace_id
```

dynamic "enabled_log" {
for_each = toset(var.log_category_groups)

```
content {
  category_group = enabled_log.value

  retention_policy {
    enabled = contains(var.log_category_groups, enabled_log.value)
    days    = contains(var.log_category_groups, enabled_log.value) == true ? var.retention_days : 0
  }
}
}
}
```

What could be the problem/issue ?

Tried with unique name for each resource diagnostic settings and set the scope to resource group level.

Comment: has this resource been created by Terraform? is there any chance to get the code is giving you this error? how did you configure the TF state backend?

Comment: @NicoMarino - yes the resource is been created by terraform.
TF state backend are created via azure devops pipeline.
Please find the below code used for one of the resource.
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "diagnostics" {name                       = "diagnostics-acr-${var.suffix}" target_resource_id         = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id log_analytics_workspace_id = var.log_analytics_workspace_id
  dynamic "enabled_log" {for_each = toset(var.log_category_types) content { category_group = enabled_log.valueretention_policy

Comment: where the TF state resides? Storage Account? If so, did you configure the backend configuration?
Please, take a look at [azurerm](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/azurerm)

Comment: Yes the state-file is stored in the storage account.

Comment: at this point, I highly recommend you to add more logs here (related to the error), maybe enabling verbosity on TF as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated the description with code.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure "Diagnostic-Settings-Name" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State.

I've taken a template from [Terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_diagnostic_setting) and deployed diagnostic settings for a specific resource.

During deployment, it shows a similar error as the name already exists because the given name is already existed in the portal. So, it will be there in terraform state file also.

[image]

The error occurs if the resources with the same name are existed and deleted previously. In this case, though it is deleted, the resource will exist in the `terraform state` file in the backend. Verify the `tf` state file and remove the unwanted resources or you can either delete the existing diagnostic setting or import it into the Terraform state.

I imported the resource as shown below:

```bash
terraform import azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.example "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keyvault|<diagnosticsettingname>"
```

*Imported successfully:*

[image]

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940884/a-resource-with-the-id-subscriptions-resourcegroups-rgaks-providers-micros/74950287#74950287) worked by me for the related issue.